# dojo AMD requestAnimationFrame

Tags: animation, dojo, amd

I'm trying to convert Dojo functions from non-AMD to AMD but am not sure how to convert the following function:
previously it was Non-AMD like

```
function step11(timestamp){
   window.requestAnimationFrame(step11);
}
```

after converting to AMD

```
step11: function(timestamp) {
   window.requestAnimationFrame(step11);
 }
```

its been called from other method as

window.requestAnimationFrame(that.step11);

I tried:

```
var that = this;
window.requestAnimationFrame(function() {
    that.step11();
});
```

Which gives the error "that.step11 is not a function".

Comment: can you provide the whole code or class ! 
i can't seeconverstion to AMD ??

Comment: bRIMOs Bor: edited the post

Comment: Please provide a bit more context. Simply showing that a function is an object property doesn't say anything about the overall implementation. Is all the code in a single `require` callback? Are there modules? Where is the code that's trying to use `step11` in relation to `step11`?

Comment: where you're calling the code `window.requestAnimationFrame(function() {hat.step11();})` in the same Class ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the solution.

```
 define(["dojo/ready", "dojo/dom", "dojo/dom-construct","js/abc", "dojo/domReady!"], function(ready, dom, domConstruct,abc){
 var test={

        step11: function(timestamp) {
          window.requestAnimationFrame(test.step11);
        }
     };
     test.step11();
     return test;
  });
```